# JPEG Corrupted file fixing

Tags: image-processing

I had an old, broken hard disk containing a lot of JPEG files.

I took that hard to an information recovery company.

The company was able to extract part of the files well, But there are many others files that look like this...

[image]

Is it possible to repair these files? The file size is the same as before, and it even shows the image information (camera used, resolution....etc.).

Comment: Clearly, the file header is not damaged and the first data rows are present. I am afraid that the rest of the blocks is forever lost. Can you have a look at the file with a binary editor ?

Comment: I checked on HxD, there is some small parts (one or two) contain 0s.
Block of consecutive zeros about 10% of the file then normal data then another block of zeros 5% of the file
like this.

Comment: As far as I know, the JPEG format includes variable-length data so that recovering after an erased area might not be doable automatically.

Comment: Consider trying a JPEG tag reader utility (not just metadata).